# Rails: Using AJAX on a "new" link to unobstrusively add multiple forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a page about cooking and I want it to make it easy to add "Kitchens" (it only has a `name` attribute), so that if I click the "Create a new kitchen" link, forms to create a new kitchen will pop out for each click, so that you can create multiple kitchens with the click of one submit button.

Would it be possible to make the `kitchens#new` action return a javascript format so that I could do `respond_to do |format|` js in `kitchens#new` in the controller and add the form using javacsript in my new.js.erb file?? Or is there another way to do that?

index.html.erb

```
<div class="createkitchendiv">


    <%= link_to "Create new kitchen", new_kitchen_path, :id => "createkitchenlink" %>


        <%= form_tag "/kitchen", :method => :post, :remote => true do %>

        <div class="blahblah">
        <%= render :partial => "box" %>

        </div>
        <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>

    <% end %>
    </div>
```

_box.html.erb (the partial/form that I want to be able to add to the page unobstrusively with the click of "Create a new kitchen". I'm not sure if this setup works with/without js. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can display whatever you want with the `new` action ;-)

The resulting form should look like this:

```
<form>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="text" name="kitchenname[]"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<input type="button" id="addNewInput" />
```

Then you would simply use jQuery to listen on `addNewInput`-button. If it get's clicked, you insert a new `<input type="text" name="kitchenname[]" />` tag to `container`-div.

Then when clicking the submit button, your controller will receive an array in `params[:kitchenname]`, which you can save to DB or whatever.

---

You may want to include the necessary JS code within your assets/javascripts/... folder. A simple small listener, that listens for click events on `#addNewInput`.

---

Edit: You can also do this without JS, but it may get a bit more complicated. You would have to make the 2nd button which is responsible for `add new input field` to cause the controller to output one more input-field than before. Additionally you may want to keep all values there were in the fields before hitting the button.

I'd go with the jQuery solution. It's pretty simple (and more Web 2.0) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you to have a look at this Railscasts revised episode on Ajax http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised

Your problem will be solved till 6:44 minute ;)